# Proof: Function Proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble proving that:

$$f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} U_{\alpha}\right) \subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} f(U_\alpha)$$

I know that I have to do something along the lines of:

If $y$ is in RHS, then by definition of a function, there is some $x \in U_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. If $\displaystyle x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} U_{\alpha}$, then by the definition of intersection we know that $x \in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in A$.

I am having some trouble going on from there. I am also questioning how rigorous this is. Can someone provide me with a proper proof?

But I am having trouble expressing it symbolically. Furthermore to make this equal what property would we have to add to $f$? Make it injective? That's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start on the left. Let $y$ be in the LHS. Then there exists $x$ in $\bigcap_\alpha U_\alpha$ such that $f(x) = y$.

This means that $x$ is in $U_\alpha$ for every $\alpha \in A$. Now since the image of $x$ is $y = f(x)$, we must have $y$ is in $f(U_\alpha)$ for every $\alpha \in A$. Therefore, $y$ is in the intersection $\bigcap_\alpha f(U_\alpha)$.

For equality, yes, injectivity will suffice.